# Why can I not run the lsp-embedded-language-service example, how should I debug?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm following the instructions of the lsp-embedded-language-service example that are written here:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/lsp-embedded-language-service.

The instructions are:

```
Running the Sample
Run npm install in this folder. This installs all necessary npm modules in both the client and server folder
Open VS Code on this folder.
Press Ctrl+Shift+B to compile the client and server.
Switch to the Debug viewlet.
Select Launch Client from the drop down.
Run the launch config.
If you want to debug the server as well use the launch configuration Attach to Server
In the [Extension Development Host] instance of VSCode, open a HTML document
Type <d| to try HTML completion
Type <style>.foo { c| }</style> to try CSS completion
Have <style>.foo { }</style> to see CSS Diagnostics
```

if I type <d| nothing happens. How should I debug this?

Comment: @rioV8 I see you removed the vscode-extensions tag, but the way I interpret the description, it should be added, I actually want to develop. Correct me if I'm wrong. "Use this tag for questions about the Visual Studio Code Extension API and extension development. Questions only about extension usage should use the [visual-studio-code] tag instead"

Comment: [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/embedded-languages#language-services) inside of the documentation they use ```<|``` for html completion maybe there is a typo inside of the github instruction .

Comment: did you actually type "`<d|`" with the "`|`"? I'm pretty sure the "`|`" is just an indicator of where the cursor/caret is after typing "`<d`". Also, have you touched the `editor.quickSuggestions` setting at all anywhere?

Comment: @Shad0w I tried < and <| and <d and <d|. Nothing worked.

Comment: @starball Yeah, I agree that the | is probably the caret. I didn't touch any code. If I open a regular .html file, I will have code completion

Comment: I don't understand. you say in the comments that when you open a HTML file, it works, but in your question body, you say it doesn't work...

Comment: @starball I'm sorry. The example uses the extension .html1, the extension represents a 'new language for illustration purpose'. Files with these extensions do not work. files with .html do have autocomplete because that is supported by another (default) extension, not the example. The reason I wrote it is to make clear that it does not seem to be a general configuration problem, but a specific problem with the example.

Comment: Please edit all the clarifications you have made here in the comments into your answer post.